# epel 6 want to update a package with the epel5 version in Centos 6

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, repository

I have downloaded and installed the epel 6 in Centos 6 using:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

but when i do:

```
yum update
```

it tries to do this update:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.41-1.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.44-1.el5.1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

First question, how is possible that yum want to update a package from el6 to el5?

If i try to install this update a lot of 404 error come out and the program finish with:

```
Error Downloading Packages:
   fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-1.el5.1.noarch: failure: fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-1.el5.1.noarch.rpm from epel: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

This is my /etc/yum.repos.d

```
adobe-linux-i386.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo            remi-release-6.rpm
CentOS-Base.repo       epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm  remi.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  epel.repo                    x2go.repo
CentOS-Media.repo      epel-testing.repo
```

Which is the correct solution to this problem?

NOTE: previousley i have installed epel5 by mistake, is there a chance that i have not remove it correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very easy solution, simply logout and login again

Comment: Logging out might work or it might not. The yum caches are fickle like that

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to reload the yum caches is:

```
yum clean all
```